# NullPointerException after Notification is clicked in notification bar(PendingIntent)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-pendingintent

I am trying to get my `PendingIntent` working but whenever I click the `notification` in the notification drawer, my app crashes.

So basically I have this java class called **CustomerCurrentlyServing.class** and when it is loaded, it retrieves all the strings passed from the previous activity as shown below:

```
    queueNo = String.valueOf(getIntent().getExtras().getInt(Constants.EX_MSG_QUEUE_NO));
    queueKey = getIntent().getExtras().getString(Constants.EX_MSG_QUEUE_KEY);
    shopName = getIntent().getExtras().getString(Constants.EX_MSG_SHOP_NAME);
    shopKey = getIntent().getExtras().getString(Constants.EX_MSG_SHOP_KEY);
    customerid = getIntent().getExtras().getString(Constants.EX_MSG_CUSTOMER_ID);
```

I implemented a method for the notification as shown below:

```
public void showNotification() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CustomerCurrentServing.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, CustomerCurrentServing.class), 0);intent.putExtra(Constants.EX_MSG_QUEUE_NO,queueNo);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.EX_MSG_QUEUE_NO,queueNo);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.EX_MSG_QUEUE_KEY,queueKey);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.EX_MSG_SHOP_NAME,shopName);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.EX_MSG_SHOP_KEY,shopKey);
    Resources r = getResources();
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setTicker(r.getString(R.string.notification_title))
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image)
            .setContentTitle(r.getString(R.string.notification_title))
            .setContentText(r.getString(R.string.notification_text))
            .setContentIntent(pi)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

It is basically opening the same class when the user clicks on the notification in the notification drawer. However, it crashes whenever I click on the notification and the error is **NullPointerException** on the line:

```
        queueNo = String.valueOf(getIntent().getExtras().getInt(Constants.EX_MSG_QUEUE_NO));
```

Any idea how to solve this error ? I have been trying to solve this error for a week and your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to add the extras to the `Intent` that you pass to `PendingIntent.getActivity()`. And you need to add them **before** you call `PendingIntent.getActivity()`. See the answer from tiny sunlight.

Answer (score 1):

You should putExtra on the Intent you pass to PendingIntent

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CustomerCurrentServing.class);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.EX_MSG_QUEUE_NO,queueNo);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.EX_MSG_QUEUE_NO,queueNo);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.EX_MSG_QUEUE_KEY,queueKey);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.EX_MSG_SHOP_NAME,shopName);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.EX_MSG_SHOP_KEY,shopKey);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent , 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, CustomerCurrentServing.class), 0);
```

here you are passing new instance of `Intent`

you should pass already created instance i.e.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CustomerCurrentServing.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

and write all those `putExtras` before creating `PendingIntent` object.

Comment: Hi, I modified the code according to your advice, but it is still showing the same NullPointerException error :(

Comment: thn you must check with the value you are passing, whether you are getting it or not, try with `getIntent().hasExtra(Constants.EX_MSG_QUEUE_KEY)` and all other values

Answer (score 0):

In this part of the code you are adding the extras to the wrong intent , you are creating an intent then creating a new one that you pass to the pending intent!

What you should be doing is this:

`Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CustomerCurrentServing.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.EX_MSG_QUEUE_NO,queueNo);
intent.putExtra(Constants.EX_MSG_QUEUE_KEY,queueKey);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.EX_MSG_SHOP_NAME,shopName);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.EX_MSG_SHOP_KEY,shopKey);`

And not creating a new intent like you did in your pending intent : 
`PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, CustomerCurrentServing.class), 0);
intent.putExtra(Constants.EX_MSG_QUEUE_NO,queueNo);`

If you do this you are putting the extras om the first intent then passing a whole new one without extras to your pending intent so when the user clicks on the notification and it opems up the activity the activity will try and get extras that dont exist thus giving a null pointer.